# Secure sharing of data between Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-sharing

I am currently helping a company with their booking system. It uses Google Sheets.

I know that data can be shared between sheets.
I am wondering if data can be shared between sheets, such that

- sheet A references sheet B.
- sheet A is readable by user, sheet B is not readable by user.

I realise that with conventional file security this is impossible. However because Google Sheets is hosted, it could be done. (like Unix set UID/GID (on executable files): Sheet A and B are owned by user U, who has all permissions, user V has read on sheet A. User U adds set GID to this copy of sheet A.)

So is it possible using Google Sheets?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Rubén Do I need to adjust any setting?

Comment: Please read [Share and work with others](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/4671185?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have found out.

1. Add formula `=importRange(«url of file B»,«range»)` to file A. This makes the content of part of one file appear in the other (the one with the formula.
2. Share file A, read only (Do not give edit/write permissions. If you give edit/write permission then they can gain read access to the other file, my editing or adding an `importRange` function).